# What does "take you in" mean?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Early on in *Revenge of the Sith*, Obi-Wan and Anakin are flying a half-burned spaceship:

> Obi-Wan: Five thousand. Fire ships on the left and the right.
>
> Pilot: We'll **take you in**.
>
> (Pilot sprays water on spaceship)
>
> [image]
>
> OBI-WAN: Copy that.

What does "take you in" mean?

Comment: For future reference, questions about what phrases mean are best addressed to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is nothing fancy exclusive to the Star Wars universe.

In this context it just means that they're going to act as an escort to their ship and guide them to a landing.

Comment: *Obi-Wan’s steady chant broke off. “Fire ships are on the left and right.” Anakin flicked a switch, and the voice of one of the fire ship pilots filled the bridge. “Follow us. We’ll put out what fire we can.” Follow you? How? But there were numbers reading out on the comm; coordinates. They’d cleared a heavy-duty landing strip in the industrial section. Strong enough to stop what’s left of this bucket of bolts, and well away from the residential areas so that if we miss, we won’t set fire to a lot of apartment buildings. Somebody’s thinking.* - Junior novel